# umap for dictionary in Julia

Tags: dictionary, matrix, julia

I'm given a dictionary with keys(ids) and values.

```
> Dict{Int64, Vector{Float64}} with 122 entries:   
  3828  => [1, 2, 3, 4...   
  2672 => [6,7,5,8...
  ...
```

Now I need to apply umap on it. I have the code that

```
embedding = umap(mat, 2; n_neighbors=15, min_dist=0.001, n_epochs=200)
println(size(embedding))
Plots.scatter(embedding[1,:],embedding[2,:])
```

Here mat is the matrix

```
1, 2, 3, 4
6, 7, 5, 8
....
```

So I got the embedding matrix and the umap plot. But in the plot all points are same color and no labels. How do I do so that I can get points with labels(keys in the dictionary)?

Comment: What is `umap`? That's not a standard function.

Comment: umap is a function for dimension reduction

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but we have no idea where it comes from and why it might fail. Please add more information.

Comment: If you can change `embedding` to a 3D array with x  = x, y = y, and z = grouping from its return formatting as an array with x the points and y the group, Plots can be told to use the z axis grouping for color.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at UMAP.jl, the input matrix should have the shape (n_features x n_samples). If each entry in your dictionary is a sample and I’m interpreting your matrix notation correctly, it appears you have this reversed.

You should be able to add the keys of the dictionary as annotations to the plot as follows (potentially with an optional additional offset to each coordinate):

```
Plots.annotate!(
    embedding[1,:] .+ x_offset,
    embedding[2,:] .+ y_offset,
    string.(collect(keys(yourdict)))
)
```

Finally, I’m not sure what variable you actually want to map to the color of the markers in the scatterplot. If it’s the integer value of the keys you should pass this to the scatter function just like above except without turning them into strings.